# Grep a variable and store the result in a vector in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a list of txt files stored in `A.path` that I would like to use `grep` on to find the year associated with that file, and save this year to a vector. However, as some of these txt files have multiple years in their text, I would only like to store the **first** year. How can I do this?

I've done similar things using `lapply`, and this is how I began approaching this problem:

```
lapply(A.path, function(i){
j <- paste0(scan(i, what = character(), comment.char='', quote=NULL),  collapse = " ")
year <- vector()
year[i] <- grep('[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]', j)
})
```

`grep` probably isn't the right function to use, as this returns the entirety of `j` for each `i`. What is the right function to use here?

Comment: you might want `gsub("^([0-9]{4}).*", "\\1", j)` but it's hard to say without example of the text you're looking at

Comment: Here's an example of the text: [link](http://pastebin.com/uTpnvqzB) @nongkrong

Comment: ok, try `gsub(".*?([0-9]{4}).*", "\\1", txt)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Converting comment to answer, you can use `gsub` with `\\1` to extract the value of the first match (ie. the text matched between `()` in the regex)

```
gsub(".*?([0-9]{4}).*", "\\1", j)
```

Comment: Also `regmatches` ( `regmatches(x,regexpr("[0-9]{4}",x))` )  or `stringr::str_extract` or `stringi::stri_extract` with similar logic.

Comment: @thelatemail are there any particular advantages to any of these methods?

Comment: @mlinegar `stri_extract(str=j, regex="[0-9]{4}")` would probably be the fastest by far (or `str_extract`, I'm not sure)